# How to pass "Source UID" to iptables?

Tags: firewall, iptables, uid

Through command line, am setting firewall rules using iptable binary like below:

`iptables -I PRIO_IN -p tcp -s "10.0.0.25/24" -d  "10.0.0.26/24" -j ACCEPT`

For above rule, now I need to add `source uid`.

In Iptables man page, am not seeing any option by name `source uid`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the iptables tag states: IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/). Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you're looking for the "owner" module for iptables. You'll find documentation under iptables-extensions (man iptables-extensions). (See here - https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbBP)

Note that it's only applicable on OUTPUT and POSTROUTING chains.

Good Luck!